# how to display animated images in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In my app i want to represent rolling dice.
currently when i roll the dice it move randomly to one of the six images without any animation.
all what i want is to display animation scene,it takes 2 second moving between six images as if the dice is rolling.
i tried with the `setState()` but it only work when i click the button is there is a way use `setState()` in `loop` and this is my state class

```
class _DicePageState extends State<DicePage> {

  int leftButtonImage = 2;
  int rightButtonImage = 3;

  void diceSoundPlayer(){
    final player = AudioCache();
    player.play('rollDice.mp3');
  }
  void changeDiceFace(){

      diceSoundPlayer();
      rightButtonImage = new Random().nextInt(6)+1;
      leftButtonImage = new Random().nextInt(6)+1;

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    changeDiceFace();
                    setState(() {

                    });
                  }
                  , child: Image.asset('images/dice$leftButtonImage.png'))),
          Expanded(
              child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    changeDiceFace();
                    setState(() {

                    });
                  }, child: Image.asset('images/dice$rightButtonImage.png'))),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  }
```

### abstract:

i have button and six images when i click button i want to display images Consecutively.

### What is the package or what should i use to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Combine CountdownTimer and AnimatedSwitcher, You can see effect of picture 
for demo, I only use 3 pictures, full code please see below

code snippet

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
          child: Image(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/${elapsed}.png'),
              key: ValueKey(elapsed)),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        ),
...
final cd = CountdownTimer(Duration(seconds: 3), Duration(seconds: 1));
    cd.listen((data) {
      setState(() {
        elapsed = cd.elapsed.inSeconds;
        print(elapsed);
      });
    }, onDone: () {
      cd.cancel();
    });
```

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quiver/async.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  int elapsed = 1;

  void _incrementCounter() {

    final cd = CountdownTimer(Duration(seconds: 3), Duration(seconds: 1));
    cd.listen((data) {
      setState(() {
        elapsed = cd.elapsed.inSeconds;
        print(elapsed);
      });
    }, onDone: () {
      cd.cancel();
    });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            AnimatedSwitcher(
              child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/${elapsed}.png'),
                  key: ValueKey(elapsed)),
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add   `_controller.repeat();` on your function or Widget build